# Debian: Downgrade from 7.9 to 7.8

Tags: debian, version

Is that possible to downgrade from 7.9 to 7.8 on Debian vm ?

Comment: I suppose so, as long as there have not been any really major upgrades, but why would you want to?

Comment: Because we should only deliver debian 7.8 and not 7.9. But I updated too fast ... Can find a way to do this ...

Comment: The older versions of packages should be at  http://snapshot.debian.org/ ... but really it's odd that you're only supposed to deliver 7.8 and not 7.9. Debian point releases are for important bug fixes only. See https://www.debian.org/News/2015/2015090502 for what was updated.

Comment: @Nico That's really weird, but sure, it should be possible. The first thing is to check the differences in packages between 7.8 and 7.9. Then you can try to downgrade them.